# "Я с друзьями" или "мы с друзьями"?

Tags: местоимения

Прошу ответить на вопрос: как правильней строить начало предложения, согласно правилам русского языка:

> Ходил с друзьями в кино.

или

> Ходили с друзьями в кино.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: А если не дан "исчерпывающий"? Но я отметил, для формальности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны оба варианта.

Форма множественного числа сказуемого показывает, *что в роли подлежащего выступает все сочетание, т.е. действие приписывается двум взаимосвязанным равноправным субъектам, например:*

> **После обеда Лось с Русаковым пошли посмотреть склады и магазины (Т. Семушкин); Встали и Вбропаев с Корытовым (П. Павленко).**

Форма единственного числа сказуемого показывает, *что подлежащим является только существительное в именительном падеже, а существительное в творительном падеже выступает в роли дополнения*, ***обозначая лицо, сопутствующее производителю действия, например:***

**>Граф Илья Андреевич в конце января с Наташей и Соней приехал в Москву (Л. Толстой);**

> **...Пришел Разметнов с Демкой Ушаковым (Шолохов).**

Подробнее можете ознокомиться здесь: [Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ.М.: ЧеРо, 1999](http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/1015483/232/Rozental_-_Spravochnik_po_pravopisaniyu%2C_proiznosheniyu%2C_literaturnomu_redaktirovaniyu.html)

Comment: Благодарю, я понимаю это. Но все же вопрос звучат так: "Как правильней?" Иными словами, оба варианта верны, но есть какой-то более употребляемый, что ли. Вопрос: "Какой?" – Денис Федоров 7 минут назад

Comment: В вашем случае корректны оба варианта и выбор за вами.

Comment: Мне кажется, обсуждение ушло не в ту сторону. Фактически вопрос о том, как правильно говорить: "я с друзьями" или "мы с друзьями". Это вопрос о числе подлежащего. Здесь нет вопроса о числе сказуемого, как у Розенталя (Сказуемое при подлежащем типа брат с сестрой). Здесь "я ходил", или "мы ходили".

Comment: Обсуждения тут еще не было вообще.

Comment: Я хотел сказать, в данном ответе рассматривается не проблема, заявленная в вопросе, а другая проблема.

Comment: @ДенисФедоров, .давайте возьмем такой пример. Отец с сыном пошел в кино(Сын маленький, решение примал отец). Отец с сыном пошли в кино( решение принимали оба).

Comment: То же и вашем примере. Если решение пойти в кино принимали вы, то правильный первый вариант. Если решение примали все вместе, то - второй.